Guid in URL breaking ASP.NET API middleware
I am creating an ASP.NET API using .NET 8 and debugging it locally using IIS Express. I have an endpoint that accepts a string in the URL, which is then converted into a Guid inside the controller. The incoming string therefore will be in a Guid format, and I am calling the endpoint as such:
[MyUrl]?MyParameter=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
This causes the middleware to fail giving me the following exception:
InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[REDACTED STACK TRACE]' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.
When debugging I can see that code actually continues into the method and executes a DB call while using the correctly passed Guid, but the API call always returns the error shown above caused by the middleware. I have tried changing the endpoint input type to Guid, changing the HTTP method to POST and receiving the Guid in the body, but none of that helped. Interestingly, if I modified the Guid in any way that makes it non-valid, i.e. removing one of the characters or adding one to alter the length format, the middleware error all of a sudden disappears. For example:
4c6c05d1-7036-b711-8147-0090569b2f58 <- This will fail as it is a valid 8-4-4-4-12 format Guid
4c6c05d1-7036-b711-8147-0090569b2f5 <- This will pass, length has been altered
4c6c05d1-7036-b711-8147-0090569b2f58x <- This will also pass, same reason
Does anyone know why this is happening? I have heard of URL Rewrite being a problem, but I am running this on IIS Express, not full IIS and I'm not sure if that is relevant here.

Add the stack trace back. Post the entire exception and the code.  That's the most important part in an exception. We can't guess what's going on or what middleware fails. xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is just a string as far as ASP.NET Core is concerned.

code actually continues into the method in that case the problem isn't the parameter at all, but something else that the code does. Perhaps it tries to return a Task instead of awaiting it?

Have you tried searching for that error? There are at least a couple questions where the real problem was returning a task instead of awaiting it.

@PanagiotisKanavos is correct. 99% chance that this has nothing to do with a GUID but rather with not awaiting the task properly. Due to timing variations, certain values may appear to work/fail.

@PanagiotisKanavos you are right, it was a problem with not awaiting the async task. I saw some threads about this but I was so caught up with the Guid length variations working that I didn't think it could be anything else. It's still interesting to me that the problem only occurs with that exact format of string.

@AssistantToTheRegionalManager you didn't post your code so we can't guess why the code returns an unawaited task in one case but not another.
